# How to change WooCommerce order total in admin orders list

Tags: woocommerce

I need to add a fee to WooCommerce order total in admin orders list.

When I make a R$65 sale, my payment gateway charges a tax, and I receive R$64,36.

How to make show R$64,36 as the order total, **but only on admin orders list**, if the customer goes to his My Account orders list, we need to show R$65,00 over there.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total` filter hook as follows:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total', 'filter_formatted_order_total', 10, 2);
function filter_formatted_order_total( $formatted_total, $order ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && isset($_GET['post_type']) && 'shop_order' === $_GET['post_type'] ){
        // HERE define the payment fee
        $payment_fee = 0.64;

        $formatted_total = wc_price( $order->get_total() + $payment_fee, array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
    }
    return $formatted_total;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.